# Obtaining the smallest step size for a (non-zero) double or float

Tags: c#, .net, floating-point, precision

For the purposes of boundary value analysis in testing, I've been looking to get the smallest step sizes for doubles or floats in .Net.  This will allow me to get the next larger and next smaller value that can be represented in a double or float.

[double.epsilon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.epsilon(v=vs.110).aspx), "applies only to Double instances that have a value of zero or an exponent of -1022".

Let's say that I have an arbitrary double or float.  What are the next larger and next smaller value that I can represent in .Net?

Based on the MSDN article, I have implemented the following code, which looks plausible:

```
private static int GetExponentWithMinorAdjustment(double value)
{
    //int indent = result.Length;

    // Convert the double to an 8-byte array.
    byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);

    int exponent = (bytes[7] & 0x07F) << 4;
    exponent = exponent | ((bytes[6] & 0xF0) >> 4);
    int adjustment = exponent != 0 ? 1023 : 1022;

    return exponent != 0 ? exponent - 1 : exponent; ;
}

private static double NextLargerNumber(double value)
{
    // Cannot use double.epsilon * Math.Pow(2, GetExponentWithMinorAdjustment(value)) as this results in infinity
    return value + Math.Pow(2, GetExponentWithMinorAdjustment(value) - 1074));
}
```

The problem with the above code is that it looks shaky.  Notice the ternary operator (inspired from the MSDN article); what's the purpose of that adjustment?

Also, while the output of several tests looks OK for positive double values, the results for negative values do not seem as good (see output image):
[image: Program Output]

What would an acceptable, correct and ideal solution to this problem look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use unsafe code to map the bits directly to an unsigned int,  increment or decrement, convert back.

Might require additional special handling at the boundaries of 0 and the special  values for infinity, Nan and so on.

Comment: Thanks - is there a way to also get the step size represented by that increment?

Comment: in the case of a float at least (i think doubles behave the same way too) it's variable depending on the precision of the number (how much of the value is used on the right of the decimal place), all you can do is take  the two values and get the difference between them at different levels of precision

Comment: Good points.  It's interesting to note that for the above examples, the original proposed code returns the same results as the increment technique proposed in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a couple extension methods I wrote to increment doubles.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Increments the magnitude of a <see cref="double"/> my the smallest increment possible.
    /// <list type="table">
    /// <listheader>
    /// <term><paramref name="value"/></term>
    /// <description>Result</description>
    /// </listheader>
    /// <item>
    /// <term><see cref="double.MaxValue"/></term>
    /// <description><see cref="double.PositiveInfinity"/></description>
    /// </item>
    /// <item>
    /// <term><see cref="double.MinValue"/></term>
    /// <description><see cref="double.NegativeInfinity"/></description>
    /// </item>
    /// <item>
    /// <term><see cref="double.PositiveInfinity"/></term>
    /// <description><see cref="double.NaN"/></description>
    /// </item>
    /// <item>
    /// <term><see cref="double.NegativeInfinity"/></term>
    /// <description><see cref="double.NaN"/></description>
    /// </item>
    /// <item>
    /// <term><see cref="double.NaN"/></term>
    /// <description><see cref="double.NaN"/></description>
    /// </item>
    /// </list>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    internal static double IncrementMagnitudeByMinimum(this double value)
    {
        if (double.IsNaN(value))
        {
            return double.NaN;
        }

        var longValue = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(value);
        var increment = BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(longValue + 1);
        return increment;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Decrements the magnitude of a <see cref="double"/> my the smallest increment possible.
    /// <list type="table">
    /// <listheader>
    /// <term><paramref name="value"/></term>
    /// <description>Result</description>
    /// </listheader>
    /// <item>
    /// <term><see cref="double.PositiveInfinity"/></term>
    /// <description><see cref="double.MaxValue"/></description>
    /// </item>
    /// <item>
    /// <term><see cref="double.NegativeInfinity"/></term>
    /// <description><see cref="double.MinValue"/></description>
    /// </item>
    /// <item>
    /// <term><see cref="double.NaN"/></term>
    /// <description><see cref="double.NaN"/></description>
    /// </item>
    /// <item>
    /// <term><see cref="double.Epsilon"/></term>
    /// <description>0E0</description>
    /// </item>
    /// <item>
    /// <term>-<see cref="double.Epsilon"/></term>
    /// <description>-0E0</description>
    /// </item>
    /// <item>
    /// <term>0E0</term>
    /// <description><see cref="double.NaN"/></description>
    /// </item>
    /// <item>
    /// <term>-0E0</term>
    /// <description><see cref="double.NaN"/></description>
    /// </item>
    /// </list>
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="value"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    internal static double DecrementMagnitudeByMinimum(this double value)
    {
        if (double.IsNaN(value))
        {
            return double.NaN;
        }

        var longValue = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(value);
        var decrement = BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(longValue - 1);
        return decrement;
    }
```

You could do something like this to just get the increment:

```
    private static double MinimumIncrement(this double value)
    {
        var longValue = BitConverter.DoubleToInt64Bits(value);
        var increment = BitConverter.Int64BitsToDouble(longValue + 1) - value;
        return increment;
    }
```